Remove duplicates based on 2 rows & specify what to do per column
I have dataset that contains:

Duplicate IDs (column ID1 and ID2) that I want to get rid of
Column List that can contain a specification (type: string) that differs between the duplicates,
And 2 columns V1 and V2 that contain values (type: int) that I want to sum between the duplicates.

A simple example of my dataset is this:
df <- data.frame(
  ID1 = c('A','A','B','C','D','D'), 
  ID2 = c('A','A','B1','C1','DE','DE'),
  List = c('LA','LA','LB','LC','L1D','L2D'),
  V1 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  V2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

> df
  ID1 ID2 List V1 V2
1   A   A    LA  1  0
2   A   A    LA  0  1
3   B  B1    LB  1  0
4   C  C1    LC  1  0
5   D  DE   L1D  1  1
6   D  DE   L2D  1  1

And I want to end up with this:
> df_final
  ID1 ID2  List_1  List_2 V1 V2
1   A   A      LA      LA  1  1
3   B  B1      LB          1  0
4   C  C1      LC          1  0
5   D  DE     L1D     L2D  2  2

So my idea was to first dcast the List column:
df <- df %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2) %>%
  mutate(Index = row_number(List))

and then to dcast with something like this:
df <- dcast(df, ID1+ID2 +V1 + V2 ~ Index, value.var = "List", fun.aggregate =sum)

But it can't handle the sumwhen also factors are involved (which makes sense). How can I best do this to get to df_final?

A base R option with aggregate + merge
merge(
    aggregate(List ~ ID1 + ID2, df, `length<-`, 2),
    aggregate(cbind(V1, V2) ~ ID1 + ID2, df, sum)
)

which gives
  ID1 ID2 List.1 List.2 V1 V2
1   A   A     LA     LA  1  1
2   B  B1     LB   <NA>  1  0
3   C  C1     LC   <NA>  1  0
4   D  DE    L1D    L2D  2  2


First summarizeing by ID1 and ID2 then using sum and also unnesting the List. If you want the NAs generated by unnest to be an empty string include the last mutate, otherwise simply leave it out.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  summarize(List=list(List), 
            across(V1:V2, ~ sum(.x)), .by = c(ID1, ID2)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(List, names_sep="_") %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("List_"), ~ replace_na(.x, "")))

output
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  ID1   ID2   List_1 List_2    V1    V2
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     A     LA     "LA"       1     1
2 B     B1    LB     ""         1     0
3 C     C1    LC     ""         1     0
4 D     DE    L1D    "L2D"      2     2

